# Javascript: Remove \n\t character from text after file upload

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to upload a file but in the file include a new line and white spaces in it.

I want to replace these new lines and white space character from my file before processing

I trying following but not working

```
onFileChange(event){
    let files = event.target.files;
    let f = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
       return function (e) {
          console.log(e.target.result.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ''));
       }
    })(f);
}
```

Above `.replace` function working on the normal string but not on uploaded file string.

Comment: I just realized I assumed the issue was getting the regex line to even run. Was that the issue? Or was the issue with the regex?

Comment: @Rayan Maybe because text is printing but not replace the newline character

Comment: what is the format of the file? if you copy the text into a plain .txt file and do it again, does it work?

Comment: Actually, the file extension is json but the text in the file in string format.

Comment: It worked for me in this jsfiddle with the changes from my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/w1mmopdh/4/.

Comment: Not working for me create `filename.json` and add `{
\n\n\t\t
"key": "value"
}` and then try.

Comment: Hmm, is the "\n\n\t\t" actually written in the file? if so, you'll need to look for the actual "\n" rather than a newline character.

Comment: Because, I just saved that file and replaced the \n with newlines and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing a line that actually reads the file. Add `reader.readAsDataURL(f)` at the end of the function. Also you can get rid of the closure.

```
onFileChange(event){
    let files = event.target.files;
    let f = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.result.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ''));
    };
    reader.readAsText(f)
}
```